# Are all the things people do already declared by Brahma Bhagwan

Tags: karma

So my question is that some people says that everything you do is written in your **hastharekha** by **Brahma**. So if everything we do is written by **Brahma Bhagwan** then why there is **Swarga** and **Naraka**?  I mean if I do good things I will go to **Swarga** and if I do bad things I will go to **Naraka**. Whereas it is not in our hand what we will be doing because it is prewritten.

So why do people says that don't do bad things God is watching. Whereas it is not in our hand that we will do bad or good things in our upcoming future.

So I am in doubt that all the things we do whether they are already written or are all the things we do our own?

Comment: Hi, a very warm Welcome to HSE!! Don't be discouraged to ask questions, even if some of them might get closed. I'd suggest you to please visit this [FAQ INDEX on the HSE META](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) , please go through it properly and then maybe get started in here for an enriching journey ahead! Also, you can always search your doubt questions, first, in the Search bar. There will always be good chances that your doubt already has been Questioned and Answered by the community before, like this similar question of yours.

Comment: Thank you for your warm suggestions. I will surely follow it.